# How to use multiple andWhere with knex in Node app?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, pg

I am trying to pass multiple columns as parameters to delete a row in `postgresql` table but after the first parameter all the rest get undefined
here is my code I am using `knex` ORM

```
const deleteDeltaTableData = (req, res, db_client) => {
  const { id, delta_type, action_type, delta_timestamp } = req.body
  console.log('id='+id);
  console.log('delta_type='+delta_type);
  onsole.log('action_type='+action_type);
  console.log('delta_timestamp='+delta_timestamp);

  db_client('delta')
    .where({id})
    .andWhere({delta_type})
    .andWhere({action_type})
    .andWhere({delta_timestamp})
  .del()
  .then(() => {
    res.json({delete: 'true'})
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).json({dbError: 'db error'});
  });
}
```

Now my `console` output is this:

```
id=f3si
delta_type=undefined
action_type=undefined
delta_timestamp=undefined
Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling DEL query: delete from "delta" where "id" = ? and "delta_type" = ? and "action_type" = ? and "delta_timestamp" = ?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my client side code first in my child compenent:

```
function onDeleteClick(id, delta_type, action_type, delta_timestamp) {
console.log(id, delta_type, action_type, delta_timestamp)
fetch('/api/delta', {
  method: 'delete',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    id,
    delta_type, action_type, delta_timestamp
  })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(row => {
  deleteItemFromState(id, delta_type, action_type, delta_timestamp)
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
}

<TableCell>
   <IconButton onClick={() => onDeleteClick(row.id, row.delta_type, row.action_type, row.delta_timestamp)} aria-label="Delete">
       <DeleteIcon  />
   </IconButton>
 </TableCell>
```

here is my parent `React` component:

```
deleteItemFromState = (id,  delta_type, action_type, delta_timestamp) => {
const updatedRows = this.state.rows.filter(
  row => 
    row.id !== id 
    && row.delta_type !== delta_type 
    && row.action_type !== action_type
    && row.delta_timestamp !== delta_timestamp
);
this.setState({ rows: updatedRows });
};

render() {
const { rows } = this.state;

return (
  <DeltaTable
    rows={rows}
    deleteItemFromState={this.deleteItemFromState }
  />
);
}
```

Comment: It seems like `req.body` does not have the desired values. What does printing it show?

Comment: @NAlex `req.body` is sending back `undefined`

Comment: So if it is undefiend, the problem is not in the added code, but where you post the form.

Comment: @NAlex here is my endpoint ` app.delete("/api/delta", (req, res) => {Delta.deleteDeltaTableData(req, res, db_client);});`

Comment: That looks fine, probably the error originates on the client code.

Comment: @NAlex here is my client function onDeleteClick(id, delta_type, action_type, delta_timestamp) {
    fetch('/api/delta', {
      method: 'delete',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
       id, delta_type, action_type, delta_timestamp
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(row => {
      deleteItemFromState(racf)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198337/discussion-between-n-alex-and-amen-ra).

Answer (score 0):

Per your console logs, req.body does not contain values for delta_type, action_type,or delta_timestamp. There's nothing wrong with your knex code -- it's just that you're feeding it undefined values. The problem exists upstream, wherever the req data is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything wrong with the knex. I believe you are not sending the correct values to the controller. I would check your requests data and body and make sure you are passing the data you wish to store.